# What counts as a witness in constructive mathematics?

Tags: analysis, philosophy, foundations, constructive-mathematics

In order for a mathematical object to be accepted by a constructivist, a *witness* of a such object much be constructed. For example, we may let points be witnesses for natural numbers. For a real number $r$, a Turning machine capable of outputting $r$ to any arbitrary precision is seen as a witness for $r$.

But what counts a witness, and why, seems quite arbitrary to me and sometimes already pre-supposes the existence of the mathematical object we are trying to construct a witness for.

Is there a more precise definition and requirements for a witness, and why or why not something counts as a witness?

Comment: There are different schools of constructivism, which indeed disagree on what a witness is.

Comment: @Noah: Don't forget the judiciary system. Eyewitnesses are not as reliable source anymore, according to some expert.

Comment: @AsafKaragila According to most experts, actually. The brain is amazing at filling in details, and people don't even notice that they're doing it.

Comment: @Arthur: And it's also very easy to implant false memories, or have the brain fill in the wrong details.